# How to merge two columns inside a two column layout with tabularx

Tags: koma-script, tabularx, two-column

I have recently decided to change my CV template to Latex and found a nice [two-column template](https://es.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/two-column-cv) that was in the web.

This template uses a class based on scrartcl to build all the objects used in the Latex document. So far I have successfully updated the class to correct all the deprecated methods that was using and have changed some stuff. However, I am unable to merge two columns in tabularx without merging the two columns of the layout.

The problem is in the *educationlist*, where I call *multicolumn{2}{l}* and instead of merging the tabularx, it merges the whole two column layout. Here is the class I use and can be opened with TeXworks:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{tccv}
              [2012/11/09 v1.0
 Two Column Curriculum Vitae]

\LoadClass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\RequirePackage[hmargin=1.25cm,vmargin=1.25cm,twocolumn,columnsep=1.25cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{bookman,etoolbox,hyperref,needspace,tabularx,xcolor,fontawesome}

% Capitalize words of at least a minimum length (default to 3 chars).
% The text is capitalized before being expanded.
%
% This macro uses Lua to do the job but fails gracefully (that is,
% return the text as is) if \directlua is not available.
%
% |[
% \ucwords[optional: miminum length]{text}
% ]|
\newcommand\ucwords[2][3]{%
    % Fails gracefully if not in LuaLaTeX
    \providecommand\directlua[1]{#2}%
    \directlua{%
    local minlen=tonumber("#1")
    local src="\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}"
    local dst={}
    for w in src:gmatch('[^\string\%s]+') do
        if w:len() >= minlen then w = w:sub(1,1):upper()..w:sub(2) end
        table.insert(dst, w)
    end
    tex.print(dst)}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\color[HTML]{303030} % Default foreground color
\definecolor{link}{HTML}{506060} % Hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=link,linkcolor=link}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{0058B6}}
\setkomafont{section}{\scshape\Large\mdseries}

% In tccv \part must contain the subject of the curriculum vitae.
% The command will start a new page and output in onecolumn the
% subject (first and last name) with the hardcoded text
% "Curriculum vitae" under it.
\renewcommand\part[1]{%
    \twocolumn[%
    \begin{center}
    \vskip-\lastskip%
    {\usekomafont{part} #1} \medskip\\
    %{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont\Huge Curriculum vitae}
    \bigskip
    \end{center}]}

% Overrides the \section command to capitalize every
% word for cosmetic purposes and draws a rule under it.
\makeatletter
\let\old@section\section
\renewcommand\section[2][]{%
    \old@section[#1]{\ucwords{#2}}%
    \newdimen\raising%
    \raising=\dimexpr-0.7\baselineskip\relax%
    \vskip\raising\hrule height 0.4pt\vskip-\raising}
\makeatother

% Allow conditionals based on the job name. This can usually be set
% from a command-line argument: check fausto.en.tex for an example.
%
% |[
% \ifjob{jobname}{content if matches}{content if does not match}
% ]|
\newcommand\ifjob[3]{%
    \edef\JOBNAME{\jobname}%
    \edef\PIVOT{\detokenize{#1}}%
    \ifdefstrequal{\JOBNAME}{\PIVOT}{#2}{#3}%
}

% Renders a personal data box:
%
% |[
% \personal[optional: web site without scheme (no http:// prefix)]
%          {address}{phone number}{email}
% ]|
\newcommand\personal[4][]{%
    \needspace{0.5\textheight}%
    \newdimen\boxwidth%
    \boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
    \colorbox[HTML]{C7E2F2}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c|X}
    \faMapMarker  & {#2}\smallskip\\
    \faPhone     & {#3}\smallskip\\
    \faEnvelope      & \href{mailto:#4}{#4}
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \faLinkedin & \href{http://www.#1}{#1}}
    \end{tabularx}}}

% Every \item can be followed by one or more paragraphs
% of description:
%
% |[
% \item{date range}{company}{role}
%
% Description of what achieved during this application.
% ]|
\newenvironment{eventlist}{%
    \newcommand*\inskip{}
    \renewcommand\item[3]{%
    \inskip%
    {\raggedleft\scshape ##1\\[1pt]}
    {\Large##2}\\[2pt]
    {\itshape ##3}
    \medskip
    \renewcommand\inskip{\bigskip}}}
    {\bigskip}

% Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
% are allowed:
%
% |[
% \item[optional: what has been achieved]{years}{subject}{notes}
% ]|
\newenvironment{yearlist}{%
    \renewcommand\item[4][]{%
    {\scshape ##2} & {\bfseries ##3} \\
    \ifstrempty{##1}{}{& {\scshape ##1} \\}
    & {\itshape ##4}\medskip\\}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{rX}}
    {\endtabularx}

% Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
% are allowed:
%
% |[
% \item[optional: what has been achieved]{years}{subject}{notes}
% ]|
\newenvironment{educationlist}{%
    \renewcommand\item[4][]{%
    {\bfseries ##3} & {\raggedleft\scshape ##2} \\
    \ifstrempty{##1}{}{{\scshape ##1} &\\}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\itshape ##4} \medskip\\}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{X r}}
    {\endtabularx}


% Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
% are allowed:
%
% |[
% \item{fact}{description}
% ]|
\newenvironment{factlist}{%
    \newdimen\unbaseline
    \unbaseline=\dimexpr-\baselinestretch\baselineskip\relax
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
    \textsc{##1} & {\raggedright ##2\medskip\\}\\[\unbaseline]}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{rX}}
    {\endtabularx}


% Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
% are allowed:
%
% |[
% \item{place}{description}
% ]|
\newenvironment{activitylist}{%
    \newdimen\unbaseline
    \unbaseline=\dimexpr-\baselinestretch\baselineskip\relax
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
    {\bfseries ##1} & {\raggedright ##2\medskip\\}\\[\unbaseline]}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{rX}}
    {\endtabularx}
%%
%% End of file `tccv.cls'.
```

The Latex document where I use the class is the following:

```
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\part{Nicola Fontana}

\section{Work experience}

\begin{eventlist}

\item{July 2007 -- Present}
     {eNTiDi software, Travagliato}
     {Management and development}

Software development for the industrial automation sector: configuration
front-end in C with interface based on GTK+,
web applications and sites on LAMP platforms grounded on the
SilverStripe framework,
supervisor programs in LabVIEW and remote system in
Lua on GNU/Linux systems.

\item{January 2002 -- June 2004}
     {TEMA s.r.l., Travagliato}
     {PLC Omron development}

Development and testing of automatic and semiautomatic machines for
ribbon winding on spools and rolls (safety belts, hook-and-loop tapes,
elastic ribbon and bindings). Designing of electrical schematics on
2D cad and user manuals drafting.

\item{October 1998 -- November 2001}
     {TWINS s.r.l., Sarezzo}
     {PC and PLC Siemens development}

Programming, installation and trial of transfer machines for assembly,
adjustment and testing of gas taps. Development and installation of PC
based semiautomatic test stands for pneumatic and hydraulic leakage
tests on valves, gas regulators, electrovalves, tanks and others.

\end{eventlist}

\section{Education}

\begin{educationlist}

\item[High school diploma]{1988 -- 1992}
     {Informatic engineer}
     {ITIS Castelli, Brescia bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}

\item{1987 -- 1988}
     {Classical gymnasium}
     {Seminario vescovile, Cremona bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla}

\end{educationlist}

\personal
    [www.entidi.com]
    {viale Conciliazione, 13\newline 25039 -- Travagliato (BS)}
    {+39 (30) 6862332}
    {ntd@entidi.it}

\section{Public projects}

\begin{yearlist}

\item{2012}
     {ntdisp}
     {Embedded devices programmer}

\item{2007}
     {tip}
     {PHP framework based on PEAR}

\item{2006}
     {adg}
     {Automatic drawing generation}

\item{2006}
     {gtk2panel}
     {Top panel menu in GTK+2}

\item{2004}
     {ntd}
     {General purpose libraries}

\end{yearlist}

\section{Communication skills}

\begin{factlist}
\item{Italian}{Native speaker}
\item{English}{Oral: fair -- Written: good}
\item{Spanish}{Oral: good}
\end{factlist}

\section{Software skills}

\begin{factlist}

\item{Good level}
     {C, PHP, HTML, CSS, autotools, git, gcc, GTK+, GObject, shell,
      MS-DOS, Linux, ladder, G-Code}

\item{Intermediate}
     {Lua, \LaTeX, MySQL, VBA, cuBasic, pascal, subversion, LabVIEW}

\item{Basic level}
     {Windows, FreeBSD, OpenIndiana, Postgres}

\end{factlist}

\end{document}
```

The result is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Try this solution:

```
\newenvironment{educationlist}{%
    \renewcommand\item[4][]{%
    {\bfseries ##3} & {\raggedleft\scshape ##2} \\
    \ifstrempty{##1}{}{& {\scshape ##1} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}\itshape ##4\end{minipage}}\medskip\\}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{X r}}
    {\endtabularx}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: I forgot \itshape out of the minipage and it is obvious in my picture... but I change it in the code and you will be fine...

Comment: It doesnt compile... Sorry... not even your original!

Comment: I will double check the code in case I copied something wrong. As for your solution, I wanted to have the date on the same line of the degree (in the first item for example, having *Informatic Engineer* aligned with the date) but then the description of the degree, I want it to be filling the whole column (in your solution this part is achieved). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found the solution... I replaced the command and the picture...

Comment: Great it works perfectly! Many thanks for your help.